# Brackets following variable declaration

Tags: c#, .net

I'm unfamiliar with the following syntax and I was wondering what happens to the variable after it exits the braces:

```
public string method(int projectid)
{
    string result = string.empty;
    var service = _service;
    {
         result = service.dosomething(); //_service implements it's own Dispose
    }

    result += "we are going to do some further operations like sum a large list that"
    result += "might take a non-trivial amount of time."

    return result;
}
```

Do the brackets that immediately follow `_service: { /* etc */ }` indicate that the service variable is only in scope for the `.dosomething()` method and that afterwards while doing X operation indicated by the `result +=` block - that the garbage collector could round up service and garbage collect it?

Basically, I want to know what the brackets surrounding `var result = service.dosomething()` are telling the compiler to do with regards to `service` and `_service`.

Comment: Does it even compile?

Comment: looking at the code, result was declared out of scope of the brackets.  Edited the original question.

Comment: That code should not compile. `result` is local to the `{ ... }`

Comment: You're declaring `var result` inside the `{}`, you can not access it outside that `{}` scope

Comment: Some of these comments are obsolete following (I presume) a ninja edit.

Comment: With the code change, I don't see any point to the `{ }`

Comment: It probably was intended to be a using block.  But here the object referenced by `_service` outlives the local scope, so `using` would be inappropriate.

Comment: I'm dealing with a EF unit of work being disposed.  There are 3 methods like the one above that are nested and somewhere the object context is disposed.  I didn't know what the syntax was doing, so hence - question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `result` is local in the `{ }`. So you can't access it outside the `service`.

Your code wouldn't even compile, since you try to assign a value to a variable that hasn't been declared.

**update**

As I can understand by your post you might want to make use of a `using` statement for using your disposable object called `service` and you are asking about what happens under the hood.

Initially, that you want can be done like below:

```
using(var service = new ...)
{
    result = service.dosomething();
}
```

In the `...` you will place the type of your service class.

If you do so, then this code will be compiled by the C# compiler to the following one

```
try
{
    ServiceType service = new ServiceType;
    result = service.dosomething(); 
}
finally
{
    if (service != null)
    ((IDisposable)service).Dispose();
}
```

*I have given* the name `ServiceType` to `...` in order to write the above sample. 
Hence, you should place there the correct type.

As you see now the `using` statement is a syntactic sugar for calling the `Dispose` method of you Disposable object. As it is stated more thoroughly and formally in MSDN

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and
>   instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the
>   Dispose method on the object *in the correct way*, and (when you use it
>   as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope
>   as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is
>   read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned. The using statement
>   **ensures** *that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you*
>   *are calling methods on the object*. You can achieve the same result by
>   putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a
>   finally block; *in fact, this is how the using statement is translated*
>   *by the compiler*. The code example earlier expands to the following
>   code at compile time (note the extra curly braces to create the
>   limited scope for the object)

Comment: If you try it (after fixing other errors) you could find that this is not true. The variable result is declared and intialized before the braces so it works and get the string

Comment: @Steve this statement `string result = string.empty;` wasn't on the original post.

Comment: OK, but you need to fix the answer because now it is wrong. (Not your fault as it seems)

Answer (score 7):

It has NO EFFECT on `service` or `_service`.

My guess (based on the comment) is that this code used to look like

```
public string method(int projectid)
{
    string result = string.empty;
    using (var service = _service)
    {
         result = service.dosomething();
    }

    result += "we are going to do some further operations like sum a large list that"
    result += "might take a non-trivial amount of time."

    return result;
}
```

and someone discovered that the object was getting used via `_service` after the using disposed it, and "fixed" the bug by removing `using` and adding a semicolon and a comment saying why `service` isn't disposed right here, leaving the braces as a useless vestige of the old buggy version.

---

NOTE: In fairness to the coder, perhaps it was originally `using (var service = GetService())` and someone decided to reuse the service instance, turning the code into the buggy version presented above, which then evolved into the current version.

Comment: Or a loop of kinds ;p

Comment: @leppie: Vestigal remains of a loop would be possible, but inconsistent with the comment.

Comment: Good catch, I did not notice that ;p

Answer (score 3):

Is Same as :

```
public string method(int projectid)
{
    string result = string.empty;
    var service = _service;
    //{
         result = service.dosomething(); //_service implements it's own Dispose
    //}

    result += "we are going to do some further operations like sum a large list that"
    result += "might take a non-trivial amount of time."

    return result;
}
```

Comment: right, but do the brackets indicate to the compiler that the service variable can be disposed/garbage collected upon getting to the result += block?

Comment: @AlexanderMatusiak no. you need a `using` for that.

Comment: @AlexanderMatusiak not at all.

Answer (score 1):

This [will print "barbaz"](http://ideone.com/lSCMlB):

```
public static void Main()
{
    string foo = "bar";

    // new scope
    {
        foo += "baz";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(foo);
}
```

Since `foo` is declared in the parent scope, it will be accessible in the child scope.

Answer (score 1):

Brackets indicate scope. Any variable inside it gets out of scope when program execution passes the end } bracket.

Now, if that variable was the *only* reference to an instance of an object, then yes, it becomes eligible for garbage collection. When the next garbace collection run is executed is indeterminate however.

In this case, the _service variable still holds a reference to the instance. So nothing will be garbage collected.

Dispose is never called by garbage collection. It must be either called from code directly or with a using statement. GC will call a finalizer if present, to close any unmanaged resources.

Comment: Objects become eligible for garbage collection after their final use; lexical scope of local variables has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you declare a varviable inside {} brackets, it is only view and acessable inside of this brackets. 
If you want to acess your var you have to declare it `var result;` in your method and initialize it in your brackets `result = service.dosomething();`

If you use it this way, you will be able to acess it.

Comment: Little late to the party. Question has been changed and `var result` is not in the `{}`

Comment: @crashmstr Aww, damn I thought I could be useful here at least once :'(

Comment: It is a fine answer for the original version.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the braces, or curly braces. Brackets are square things.

Braces establish a new local scope. Variables defined inside this scope are local to the scope.

A local variable that has a destructor will have that destructor executed on leaving the block.

With the code as currently written, neither of those things will happen.